# Content Property for NavigationViewItem Problem

Tags: uwp-xaml

I'm trying to use the NavigationView control in Windows 10 XAML and I'm unable to figure out how to set the Content name value in a child tag.

Normally, you would type the following code and the Content property will provide the display name for the navigation view item:

`

```
<NavigationView x:Name="nvSample">
    <NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <NavigationViewItem Icon="Play" Content="Menu Item1" Tag="SamplePage1" />
```

`

However, I wish to display alternate content in the frame, but I'm not able to set the ContentControl.Name property (the Content property is a ContentControl object) when using the child tag in the following way:

`

```
<NavigationView x:Name="nvSample">
    <NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <NavigationViewItem Icon="Play" Tag="SamplePage1">
            <NavigationViewItem.Content>
                <TextBox Text="Sample" />
```

`

I've tried setting x:Name="Sample" and just Name="Sample" in the Content tag and in the parent NavigationViewItem tag, but neither of these will cause the control in the designer to populate the text.

Image of the designer (I want text next to the Play button):

[image: designer view]

Can anyone explain if it is possible to set the ContentControl.Name property somehow in this format?

Comment: What exactly would you like to put next to the "Play" icon? A TextBox? Or just some other text? Why don't you simply set Content to some other text?

Comment: Your code worked well on my side. See [Screenshot](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoI4pKdRYn8KnG_EPB-ym9n9ibXq). What's your OS build version? What's your project's target version? My OS build is 1809. My project's target version is 17763.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT My screenshot was using 1803, but I will add that I don't want to put a TextBox there, I want the button to operate the same as the other buttons where the text next to the button comes from the Content tag, i.e. Content="Tables" or Content="Entities". When I override the Content tag with an object, I'm not able to set the text that shows up next to the button.

Comment: @AaronStackpole Sorry, I cannot understand what you're doning. In your above code, you put a TextBox in the NavigationViewItem.Content, but you said 'I don't want to put a TextBox there'. I'm confused what exactly you are trying to put there.

Comment: The first block of code is a sample of how you can put content into the content block, but if you do that, you cannot use the text label for the control. I'm not sure how I can explain it more clearly. Sorry. The second block of code shows how you cannot set the label for the control when you specify the content block.